# Console -> Internal Server Error (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp

If i try to launch the cake-console nothing happens. No output to my window.

At the next step i tried the following command: *php5 cake.php*

But i got an internal server error.

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html
```

My other cake project on the same webspace works with both methods written above.
Anybody got an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: No idea of why you get HTTP headers on the command line but "500 Internal Server Error" means "please see Apache logs for the error message".

Comment: HTTP headers through the CLI? Now that's unlikely... what's your setup like?

Comment: SOLUTION: I tried *php54 cake.php* and it worked. Changed the following line to php 5.4 and everything is fine: _exec php54 -q "$CONSOLE"/cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"_